# How can we setup minDate for datetime-local dynamically?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two inputs one start date and other end date and I want end Date to have min as Start date. How can I populate end date to be same as start date when start date is filled and the min to be start date as well and disabled otherwise

```
<div>
    <small id="inputHelp" class="form-text text-muted-hint">Enter Time (UTC Format)</small>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="startTime">Start Time:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="startTime" ng-model="startTime" max="{{maxDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'}}">
</div>
{{startTime}}
<div>
    <label for="endTime">End Time:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="endTime" ng-model="endTime" [disabled]="!startTime">
</div>
```

The endDate is disabled as of now. New to angular not sure how to handle the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below working code:

```js
function handler(e) 
{
    document.getElementsByName("endTime")[0].min = e.target.value;
        document.getElementsByName("endTime")[0].value = '';
        document.getElementsByName("endTime")[0].disabled = false;
    }
```

```html
<div>
        <small id="inputHelp" class="form-text text-muted-hint">Enter Time (UTC Format)</small>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="startTime">Start Time:</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="startTime" ng-model="startTime" max="{{maxDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'}}" onchange="handler(event)">
    </div>
    {{startTime}}
    <div>
        <label for="endTime">End Time:</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="endTime" id="endTime" ng-model="endTime" disabled>
    </div>
```

**Rest I know you will manage from your end the framework part.**
Please let me know if you find any issues with the code

Comment: Hi Thank you, this is working but I am unable to disable the End Time input. either it remains disabled or enabled for whole time.

Comment: Please check updated answer snippet code. This will help you

Comment: Please let me know if above answer is okay for you or not

Comment: Great. I am happy that it's worked for you. Thanks for confirmation